# WCF REST service and client notifications

Tags: .net-4.5, wcf-rest, windows-mobile-6, firebird-3.0

Here is my situation: I have a Firebird database, a WCF REST service (.NET 4.5) and a Windows Mobile 6 client. What I need is: on Firebirds post event, WCF REST should notify the client.

I know that WCF has duplex communication when used as SOAP service, but I can't use it due framework version incompatibilities. Any ideas? Is this even possible and if not are there any alternatives? I'm generally new to WCF so I'm probably missing something, but I couldn't find anything helpful for my particular situation.

P.S If you need code snippets from my service let me know. There is a lot of it and I'm trying to keep this post as clean as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [ASP.NET Web API 2](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) over WCF for developing Rest services and [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr).

Web API would be for your REST web services and SignalR to notify all your clients when Firebird posts an event.

> SignalR allows bi-directional communication between server and client.

Sample Hub:

```
public class SomeHub: Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't going to work for me because SingalR's client isn't supported on windows .net CE, although still useful suggestion for future projects.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, but i'm not entirely sure how good it is.
First i made WCF method that is used to "Subscribe" to events

Interface declaration

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
 BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "Notification")]
 Stream Notification();
```

Service class implementation

```
public Stream Notification()
{
        string result= "";
        using (FbConnection conn= new FbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            FbRemoteEvent events= new FbRemoteEvent(conn, "event1", "event2", "event3", "event4");
            events.QueueEvents();
            AutoResetEvent waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            eventi.RemoteEventCounts += (sender, args) => 
            {
                if (args.Counts > 0)
                {
                    result= args.Name;
                    waitHandle.Set();
                }
            };
            waitHandle.WaitOne();
        }

        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
}
```

I'm using AutoResetEvent to freeze service instance until post_event happens and once it does happen AutoResetEvent's Set() method is called to unfreeze service and return in my case events name, so i know which event triggered.
On client side i'm calling this method in seperate thread and waiting for its response, once i get it i process it accordingly and resend same method request again so i can catch next post_event.

P.S. You should set your InstanceContextMode to PerCall for this to work.